# viewModelScope SupervisorJob() cancelling the 3rd launch { } block

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I was under the impression if i use viewModelScope which internally uses SupervisorJob(), will keep the 3rd launch { } block running an will print API 3 as well. But the output is different? Why is this happening?

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = "This is home Fragment"
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text

    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("API exception caught: $exception")
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }
    fun test() {
        viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
            launch {
                println("API 1 launch executing")
                apiCall("API 1", 1000)
            }
            launch {
                println("API 2 launch executing")
                delay(1500)
                throw NullPointerException("Exception")
            }
            launch {
                println("API 3 launch executing")
                apiCall("API 3", 2000)
            }
            delay(4000)
            println("API no api its ended.")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun apiCall(message: String, time: Long) {
        delay(time)
        println(message)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16:08:50.314  I  API 1 launch executing
16:08:50.314  I  API 2 launch executing
16:08:50.314  I  API 3 launch executing
16:08:51.317  I  API 1
16:08:51.819  I  API exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three parallel coroutines are all children of the single parent coroutine because you used its scope to launch them. That scope of the parent coroutine is a child of `viewModelScope` and is not a supervisor so the child coroutines cannot fail independently.

Either launch each of the parallel coroutines directly from `viewModelScope` or wrap the three of them with `supervisorScope` to create a local supervisor for launching them as children.

Edit:
Examples:

```
viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        println("API 1 launch executing")
        apiCall("API 1", 1000)
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        println("API 2 launch executing")
        delay(1500)
        throw NullPointerException("Exception")
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        println("API 3 launch executing")
        apiCall("API 3", 2000)
    }
    delay(4000)
    println("API no api its ended.")
}
```

Or

```
viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
    supervisorScope {
        launch {
            println("API 1 launch executing")
            apiCall("API 1", 1000)
        }
        launch {
            println("API 2 launch executing")
            delay(1500)
            throw NullPointerException("Exception")
        }
        launch {
            println("API 3 launch executing")
            apiCall("API 3", 2000)
        }
    }
    delay(4000)
    println("API no api its ended.")
}
```

Comment: Any code snippet for the change you are suggesting will be helpful.

Comment: I tried multiple things and it doesn't work. ex: viewModelScope.launch(SupervisorJob() + handler) { ... }
If i use viewModelScope.launch { } for the 3 internal child coroutines. API 3 still not getting printed.

Comment: See my update for examples of the two different ways to fix it I described.

Comment: Also note that with the first way it’s kind of a hack to be using a delay to wait for the sibling coroutines since that doesn’t provide a guarantee of order of events, although we are working with such big delays that shouldn’t matter. With the second way, the code outside the supervisor scope won’t be called until all three child coroutines are done.

Comment: 1st code sample doesn't work, it behaves the same way. 2nd code sample with supervisorScope  { } works but does that not conflict with the fact that viewModelScope already has supervisorJob() that is supposed to do the exact same thing?

Comment: Sorry about the first. Been away from computer all day and was going off memory so I’m not sure what I have missing. 

Regarding the second one, no. Your outermost launch call starts a new coroutine that gets its own scope that is the child of the viewModelScope, and it does not inherit its supervisor behavior.

Comment: Are you sure your code exactly matches what is in your question. It’s odd to me you don’t see “API 3” printed before the exception is thrown. And my first code block should at least differ from your code’s behavior as far as printing when an exception is thrown, since there is no custom exception handler for the coroutine that throws.